# Phpseclib AES decryption fails on string longer than 16 characters

Tags: java, encryption, aes, phpseclib

We are using phpseclib to implement AES decryption on server side and using Java-Android AES client. When the string is longer than 16 characters, the decryption fails, but if the string to decrypt is less than 16 characters it works fine. On server side we are using 128bits key. When we try longer string directly with php client, the decryption works fine, any idea what can be happening?

Comment: Code, input, output and a complete error description please.

Comment: "Desencryptaion"? Do you mean *decryption*? Don't just make words up.

Comment: That sounds like a block chaining issue. Things that come to mind are that you used a different AES Chaining mode, ie CBC vs ECB vs GCM etc. 16 one byte characters is a typical block size.

Answer (score 0):

Your topic is not clear enough... What dot you mean telling 16 characters? AES is block cipher and each block of encrypted / plaintext data MUST be 16 bytes long. Or if you have long message to decrypt, the length of message must be multiple of 16 bytes (not characters).

Wbr, 
Juris